# Long press of NavigationView only work on the left part, not all the NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Following is a NavigationView, the view pops to `Destination2` when long press the NavigationLink and to `Destination1` when normally tap it. But the right zone of the NavigationLink in the picture cannot be long pressed.

Does anyone know the reason? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isLongPressed = false
    @State var currentTag: Int?

    let lyrics = ["OutNotWorkA", "OutNotWorkB", "OutNotWorkC"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List {

                ForEach(0..<lyrics.count) { index in
                    VStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                           NavigationLink(destination: Group
                                { if self.isLongPressed { Destination2() } else { Destination1() } }, tag: index, selection: self.$currentTag
                            ) {
                                Text(self.lyrics[index])
                            }


                        }
                    }.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
                        print("Got Long Press")
                        self.currentTag = index
                        self.isLongPressed = true
                            })
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                        print("Got Tap")
                        self.currentTag = index
                        self.isLongPressed = false
                    })
                    .onAppear(){
                        self.isLongPressed = false
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Destination1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination1")
    }
}

struct Destination2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination2")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because gesture is handled by *opaque part of label*, ie `Text(self.lyrics[index])` only.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks. Then how to handle the whole part?

Comment: See the fix in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then how to handle the whole part?

Find below the fix

```
VStack{
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
       NavigationLink(destination: Group
            { if self.isLongPressed { Destination2() } else { Destination1() } }, tag: index, selection: self.$currentTag
        ) {
            Text(self.lyrics[index])
        }


    }
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())           // << here !!
.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
```

Answer (score 0):

LongPressGesture only works on the visualized part of the label.

The easiest way to handle this problem is a little workaround with a lot of spaces:

```
Text(self.lyrics[index]+"                                                                   ")
```

Because only using spaces doesn't create a line break this makes no visual problems in your App.

Comment: In this way, there is no tapping sign, ie. turning to be a little grey on the tapped NavigationLink.

Comment: That's true, but this is standard SwiftUI behaviour. Using ".contentShape(Rectangle())" results in the same. Of course you could manually create this grey tapping look if you change backgroundColor withAnimation onTap.